# HTML Button - How to dynamically change url content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change values in a button's URI to input texts values.

```
<div class="numcontainer">
    <input required="required" onchange="getNumber()" id="cnt" type="input" name="input" placeholder="ISD">
    <input required="required" onchange="getNumber()" id="wano" type="input" name="input" placeholder="Enter number">
</div>
<button type="submit"  name="gowa" id="btngo"  onclick="location.href='myserver://send?phone=NumberPlaceHolder'">Go!</button>
```

`NumberPlaceHolder`: Trying to concatenate values enter in both input

JS:

```
function getNumber() {
    document.getElementById('btngo').href.replace("NumberPlaceHolder",document.getElementById('cnt').value+document.getElementById('wano').value); 
}
```

It does not work as expected. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an alternative, it's cleaner

```js
const getNumber =()=> {
    let val =id=> document.querySelector(id).value
    console.log('myserver://send?phone='+val('#cnt')+val('#wano'))
}
//console or location.href
```

```html
<div class="numcontainer">
   <input required id="cnt" type="text" placeholder="ISD">
   <input required id="wano" type="number" placeholder="Enter number">
</div>
<input type="button" name="gowa" id="btngo" onclick="getNumber()" value="Go!">
```

`onChange` is quite unnecessary.

Comment: what's `el` here?

Comment: It's the parameter for the element, sec I'll edit to 'id', better

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a `href` attribute for a button. You need to change the `onclick` attribute here:

```
function getNumber(){
  document.getElementById('btngo').setAttribute("onclick", document.getElementById('btngo').getAttribute("onclick").replace("NumberPlaceHolder", document.getElementById('cnt').value+document.getElementById('wano').value)); 
}
```

It's always better to have it split like this:

```
function getNumber(){
  curOnclick = document.getElementById('btngo').getAttribute("onclick");
  wanoValue = document.getElementById('cnt').value+document.getElementById('wano').value;
  newOnclick = curOnclick.replace("NumberPlaceHolder", wanoValue);
  document.getElementById('btngo').setAttribute("onclick", newOnclick); 
}
```

Comment: oops !! I have a problem again .. I works only for first time when I refresh the  page and put another number it shows NumberPlaceholder instead of actual input number

Comment: @rimboche Awesome. Can you make a [mcve] so that I can look into it well?

Comment: For exampple, I put a number for the first time and when I click the button it will work as expected but when I go back and put another number in the text field the method not taking given number

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple

```
<a href="myserver://send?phone=NumberPlaceHolder"></a>
```

instead of

```
<button type="submit" name="gowa" id="btngo" onclick="location.href='myserver://send?phone=NumberPlaceHolder'">Go!</button>
```

To change link use this:

```
document.querySelector('.start a').href = 'my-new-address'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type like this `type="nummber"` or `type="text"` for getting number or text only

```
<input required="required" onchange="getNumber()" id="cnt" type="nummber" placeholder="ISD">
<input required="required" onchange="getNumber()" id="wano" type="number" placeholder="Enter number">
```

You can add click event to your button like this.

```
function getNumber(){
     document.getElementById("btngo").onclick = function() {
        var ll = "myserver://sendphone="+document.getElementById('cnt').value+document.getElementById('wano').value;
        console.log(ll); // checking url in console.
        location.href = ll;
     };
 }
```